# Proof Group Homomorphism: $\varphi(e)= e'$ & $\varphi(\hat{a})= \widehat{\varphi(a)}$

Tags: group-theory

I would like to proof the following Lemma:

A group homomorphism $\varphi$ from $\langle G;\ast,\hat{},e  \rangle$ to $\langle H;\star,\hat{},e'  \rangle$ satisfies:

1)

$\varphi(e)= e'$

Proof: $\varphi(e)=\varphi(e\ast e)=\varphi(e)\star\varphi(e)=e'\star e'=e'$

2)

$\varphi(\hat{a})= \widehat{\varphi(a)}$

Proof: $\varphi(e)=\varphi(\hat{a}*a)=\varphi(\hat{a})\star\varphi(a)=e'$ which requires $\varphi(\hat{a})= \widehat{\varphi(a)}$ from the definition of $e'$

I don't know whether the above proofs are valid. Maybe some improvement on the notation?

Comment: The proof is correct. If you are used to groups, you can even omit writing out the group operations and write for both identities $e$. In most references, the inverse of $a$  is denoted by $a^{-1}$

Comment: @MPos no, 1) is wrong as it stands, it is a self biting snake.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) is wrong because you used the very equality that you are trying to prove, namely at the step $$\varphi(e)\star\varphi(e)=e'\star e'$$

2) is perfect.

A correct way for 1) is to say that $\varphi(e)\star\varphi(e)=\varphi(e)$ implies that $\varphi(e)=e^\prime$ by left- (or right-) cancellation. That is, by multiplying both sides by $\widehat{\varphi(e)}$, whatever that may be. In one line:

$\varphi (e)=\varphi(e)\star \varphi(e)\star \widehat{\varphi (e)}= \varphi (e\star e)\star \widehat{\varphi (e)}= \varphi(e)\star \widehat{\varphi (e)}=e^\prime $

Comment: I agree. Could formulate your proof as above, then I can accept it as a solution since it is true and consistent in the format.

Comment: @Waterhouse in one line like this?

Answer (score 0):

For 1):

Let $x=\varphi(e)$

$$
\varphi(a)=\varphi(ea)=\varphi(e)\varphi(a)=x\varphi(a)
$$
Multiply by $\widehat{\varphi(a)}$ on the right, conclude $e'=x$.

Comment: @Waterhouse Suggests an edit to change $\varphi(a)^{-1}$ to $\widehat{\varphi(a)}$, is it correct? I can't approve edit because I don't know about this stuff.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Yes, it was just easier to type :)